# create step chart using xlsxwriter module

Tags: xlsxwriter

I need to create a step chart using xlsxwriter. I have looked into documentation but could not find any information. Is it possible to create a step chart using xlsxwriter?

https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/chart.html

Comment: I don't know what you mean by step chart and I wrote that module and documentation. What is a the feature in Excel that you are looking for.

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for reply. Please find the url for stepchart. it can create by duplicate value and with Error bar(I heard and not sure). Please find the url which create step chart using duplicate value http://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-step-charts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To quote your link *"A step chart in Excel can be created from a regular line chart and some clever formatting of your data"*.

[XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/working_with_charts.html) supports line charts so I guess that it is up to you to do the clever formatting of the data.